# Create a verb from of the word "surgeon/surgery"

Tags: verbs

Is it possible to create a verb from the word "surgery" or "surgeon", which will has the same meaning as "to operate"?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285456/is-there-a-verb-form-of-the-word-surgery

Comment: There is only "cut", once common in Britain, e.g. "Mr Smith will cut" (Male surgeons are traditionally called Mr as a courtesy, always in Britain and Ireland, sometimes in Australia  and New Zealand, rarely anywhere else).

Comment: This is dictionary stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No

"Surge" is a verb, but it doesn't mean "to do surgery". The closest meaning is "to operate a surger" (a type of sewing machine) and that is not the usual meaning of the verb.

Not every noun has  a corresponding verb derived from the same root.  The matching verb here is "operate" (or in older usage "cut") or just "perform surgery".

Sometimes a verb derived from a noun does not have a meaning obviously associated with the noun, or no longer does. Fort example there are two nouns derived from "road": they are "ride" and "raid". "Ride" is what one does along a road. and "raid" is what hostile riders do.. The connection goes back, if I am not mistaken, to Old English.

Comment: I think it's idiomatic to say "perform surgery" rather than "do surgery".

Comment: @Canadian Yankee Yes  "perform surgery i the more common expression, I', not sure why I didn't use it in the answer. "Do surgery" is not incorrect, but much less common. I have corrected the answer.